# How to create dot net core SAML application

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, saml-2.0, adfs, federation

We have an ADFS 4 server and I'm trying to create a dot net core web app in Visual Studio 2019 that uses SAML "flow" for authentication/authorization.

I remember seeing a tool/extension in an old version of Visual Studio (2015?) that allowed you to configure some details of authentication.

But in VS2019, when I select "Cloud - Single Organization" on the new app wizard, I can't tell whether it's creating WSFed, SAML or OAuth protocol app.

Is it because AzureAD defaults to SAML?

[image: create app wizard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - Azure AD defaults to OpenID Connect.

Yes - there was a tool back in the day but that was for WS-Federation (WIF).

There was a SAML implementation of WIF for a brief moment but it was withdrawn and never formed part of the tool.

Microsoft has never had an official SAML client stack.

There are a number of options [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Comment: No Microsoft/.NET stack for SAML clients, and no OpenID support in ADFS. Is that correct?

Comment: No Microsoft/.NET stack for SAML clients - yes

Comment: No OpenID support in ADFS. If you mean OpenID - no. If you mean OpenID Connect then yes. ADFS has support for this downstream i.e. to clients.

Comment: In Visual Studio, Right Click on your dotnet core Project > Add > New Scaffolded Item... > Identity